# Get an element of a list where something is static

Tags: python, json, request

I'm using an API where the request.json gives me back a list inside a list inside a list inside a list.
I recently got an answer how to access these lists and their elements.
However I don't know a way to get a specific list.
So it's like this:

```
 
{
  "name1": {
  },
  "name2": {
    "something1": 213,
    "something2": [
      {
        "info1": 123,
        "info2": 324
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and i need to get info1 which is a variable from a list where info2 is which is static and does not change.
There's 10 "somethings" and info2 is an id.
How can I check for info2 while trying to get info1?
I used this to get info1:

```
r.json()['name2']['something2'][0]['info1']
```

but i need 'something2' to be match 'info2'

Basically I need info1 from somethingX where info2 = xyz(set known value)

```
r.json()['name2']['something2'][0]['info1']
```

always gives me the 1st item of the 'name2'

Comment: You will want to break this up a bit.  Start by getting the list of `something2` and iterating over it. Test each item for the condition you seek to find the item you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the dictionary elements.

```
data = r.json()['name2']
For val in data.values():
    if val['info2'] == xyz:
        print(val['info1'])
        break
```